# Removing keyword from list after matching the keyword with answer

Tags: c#

I'm trying to keep score after certain keywords are matched with output from a chatbot. I got it to count a score for every match, but I dont want to match it again if there will be a match with the same keyword. I'm  trying to do this by removing the keyword from the list, but it continues to add score.

i.e. I want to add score if chatbot say hi, but only once.

I'm tring this

```
public void SendQuestionToRobot()
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputField.text) == false)
    {

        string answer = bot.getOutput(inputField.text);

        robotOutput.text = answer;

        inputField.text = "press enter to type";

        List<string> sPattern = new List<string> { "hi", "a painkiller" };



        foreach (string s in sPattern)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(answer, s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                controller.score += 5;
                sPattern.Remove(s);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and

```
public void SendQuestionToRobot()
{

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputField.text) == false)
    {

        string answer = bot.getOutput(inputField.text);

        robotOutput.text = answer;

        inputField.text = "press enter to type";

        List<string> sPattern = new List<string> { "hi", "a painkiller" };



        foreach (string s in sPattern)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(answer, s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                controller.score += 5;
                break;
            }
        }
        foreach (string s in sPattern)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(answer, s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                sPattern.Remove(s);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

but in both cases the score continues to be added

Comment: you recreate the list each time. You must load it once into something longer lived (a global variable, a class member)

Comment: Perfect, it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why dont you use a `for` loop instead, you can remove it then quite easily.

Answer (score 3):

As is often the case: if you eliminate the loop, you eliminate the chance of writing a buggy loop. Don't write a loop at all!

```
string match = sPattern.FirstOrDefault(
  s => Regex.IsMatch(answer, s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
if (match != null) {
  controller.score += 5;
  sPattern.Remove(match);
}
```

No loop; no loop problems.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to renew sPattern when needed.

```
List<string> sPattern = new List<string> { "hi", "a painkiller" };

public void SendQuestionToRobot()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputField.text) == false)
    {

        string answer = bot.getOutput(inputField.text);

        robotOutput.text = answer;

        inputField.text = "press enter to type";

        foreach (string s in sPattern)
        {

            if (Regex.IsMatch(answer, s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                controller.score += 5;
                sPattern.Remove(s);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot **break** in the second foreach. You can't run foreach over collection that you modify inside Foreach!!!! Enumerator allows you only to READ. It becomes not valid after you modify collection.

```
foreach (string s in sPattern)
    {

        if (Regex.IsMatch(answer, s, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            sPattern.Remove(s);
            break;
        }
    }
```